# Registering Azure App Service application to use Google Login

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, mobileserviceclient

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms application and using Azure's Authentication/Authorization to add Facebook and Google as authentication providers. In my code, I am using the LoginAsync() from MobileServiceClient class to perform the login for both Facebook and Google.

I am able to successfully authenticate Facebook users. However, with Google login, once the code executes LoginAsync(), it takes the user to Google's sign-in page (https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/...) and just stops there. The page is blank and nothing is displayed.

[Screenshot of empty page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlP8C.png)

I tried logging in using Chrome with my azure app url (https://traveldiary.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback) and Google login shows up and when I select my gmail account to access the site, I get to a page that shows the message:

traveldiary.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I have followed all the steps to configure Google Login from Microsoft site - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google). Is there any other setting that is missing that I have to add to make Google sign-in page show up and then redirect to my authorized Redirect URI once successfully logged in.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users) maybe help.

Comment: I have followed the steps from that link as well but there is no difference. There must be something to do with Google redirect. If I use, https://traveldiary.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback, I can successfully login and return back to azure.